# static NSString *const - throws error 'Unknown type name 'NSString'' in iOS

Tags: ios, error-handling, constants

I'm just copied the below line from my existing application's(Say app A) constants header file (Constants.h) to my new app's (Say app B) constants header file (Constants_new.h)

```
static NSString *const xxx = @"yyy";
```

This line does not show any error/warning with my app A. But when I copy this line to my app B's constants_new.h file, it throws an error as,

> Error: Unknown type name 'NSString'

Please help me to resolve this.

P.S: If I copy the whole file content of constants.h, and paste it to the constants_new.h file, there is no error.

Comment: import UIKit framework to resolve issue.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Seems that you forgot to import Foundation classes in your app B's `constants_new.h` file:

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
```

Answer (score 3):

Make sure you import UIKit in your .h file.
Add the following line on the top of your .h file

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
```